# Docusign One click Sign-in

Tags: docusignapi

Hi @all **DOCUSIGN** users,

Instead of reviewing the document and sign in every pages of the envelop document, i need to make the process simple. We will show the documents as like Terms & Conditions with agree option. Thus required to get the customer signature, only once in a form (basically within the application) and automatically signed off on every template document, in respective places, with that **eSignature**. Please suggest me the possibility to do with Docusign in a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option for single-click is to use the DocuSign Click product with clickwraps.
Here is an example of using it for [Terms and Conditions](https://myclickwrap.sampleapps.docusign.com/termsandconditions/) just like you asked.
See if this does what you want.